# Create a List from nested for loop out put values in Python 3

Tags: python-3.7

I have nested for loop out put as below and want to create a list from this out put values. Please suggest me how to achieve this.

for loop output values:

```
Order_Numbers:
1234_90
3456_80
9876_70
2345_23
```

Expected:
List = `[1234_90, 3456_80, 9876_70, 2345_23]`

Answer (score 0):

You can initial the list outside the for loop and keep appending the value inside the "for" loop. Pseudocode is given below, since the question is not very clear.

```
for .... (outer loops):
    order_number_list = [] #Initialize the list
    for.... (actual loop where the ordered number is created):
         order_number_list.append(number) #appends number to the created list
    print(order_number_list) #Doing this outside the innermost for loop is going to print expected output.
```